# Integral value of monotone function

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, monotone-functions

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow R$ a monotone function (lets suppose increasing for the discussion)

Prove that exist point $c \in [a,b]$ such that:

$\int_{a}^{b} f \,dx = f(a)(c-a)+f(b)(b-c)$

I was able to prove that $f(a)(b-a)≤\int_{a}^{b} f\,dx≤f(b)(b-a)$

with Riemann sums both got stuck, note that $f$ is not necessary continues so the IVT theorem can't be used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integrals equality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146645/integrals-equality) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_%7Ba%7D%5E%7Bb%7Df(x)dx%3Df(a)(c-a)%2Bf(b)(b-c)%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24c%5Cin%5Ba%2Cb%5D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Amonotone&p=1). FYI, there's also the fairly closely related [Prove that there is a unique real number $\mu\in (a,b)$ such that $\int_a^bf(t)dt=(\mu-a)c+(b-\mu)d.$](/q/3820283).

Comment: You have actually solved the problem as the integral is located between the values $g(a)$ and $g(b)$  of the function $g(x)=f(a)(x-a)+f(b)(b-x)$